# How to call LostFocus event of another control from the other control

Tags: c#, wpf

Calling the `LostFocus` event of control from other control

Example. : I want to call `LostFocus` event of `Button1` button from the `Gotfocus` event of `Button2` button.

code is :-

```
private void button2_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          button1.gotFocus // this line giving error.
       }
```

Comment: cant u call another method from one method!?

Comment: yes we can call but call event from other i dnt have much knowledge about it

Comment: event is nothing but kindof function. Please post what u have tried

Comment: You have said u want to call LostFocus and in code u r trying to call GotFocus?

Comment: oh sorry any event whether got or lost

Comment: give the focus to some other UI elements around, The event would get called automatically :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following code:

```
private void button2_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(LostFocusEvent, button1));
}


private void button1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, post your code and state your problem and purpose clearly so that you can get better solution.

Comment: If it is working and your issue got resolved with the help of this post, then you should mark this post as answer.

Comment: oh sry ma net connection waz disconnected

Answer (score 1):

you can just call event handler method of `Button1`'s `LostFocus` event in `button2_GotFocus` :

```
private void button2_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    button1_LostFocus(this.button1, null); 
}
```

Comment: Error 2 The event 'System.Windows.UIElement.LostFocus' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Taborder\WpfApplication2\MainWindow.xaml.cs 44 20 WpfApplication2  (giving error)

Comment: `button1_LostFocus` is the event handler method of `button1`'s `LostFocus` event. I suspect you tried with `button1.LostFocus` instead of `button1_LostFocus`?

Comment: private void button1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void button2_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           button1.LostFocus(sender, e); // error here
       }

Comment: oh sorry yes i did that only

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     private void button2_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       { 
         button1_LostFocus(sender,e)

       }
```

Comment: it is giving error :-  like (Error 2 The event 'System.Windows.UIElement.LostFocus' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Taborder\WpfApplication2\MainWindow.xaml.cs 44 20 WpfApplication2
)

Comment: In this way in sender you would not get the button1 but the button2 object and in e.RoutedEvent you will get GotFocusEvent not the LostFocusEvent which is wrong.